# Custom code works in Visual Studio but not on Report Server

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ado.net, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I have added some custom code to a report in SSRS2005 that works perfectly in BIDS2005 but not when I deploy to the server.  Here is the custom code:

```vb
Public Function GetUsers(ByVal param As Integer) As String
    Dim sqlCon As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim dRet As String
    Dim sCmdText As String

    sqlCon.ConnectionString = "data source=MYSERVER;initial catalog=MYDB;Integrated Security=true"

    cmd = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    sCmdText = "SELECT dbo.udf_MyFunction(" 
    'cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = sqlCon
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

    sCmdText = sCmdText & param
    sCmdText = sCmdText & ")"

    cmd.CommandText = sCmdText
    If sqlCon.State <> System.Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
    sqlCon.Open()
    End If
    dRet = cmd.ExecuteScalar() & ""     
    sqlCon.Close()

    Return dRet

End Function
```

In order to use this code, I had to add this assembly:

```
System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

When the user clicks on a particular text box, a value from the report is passed to the SQL function and a list of integers is returned to a detail report.  In BIDS, this works perfectly every time.  However, I have deployed this on two different report servers and it does not work.  The detail report opens up but nothing is passed.

The frustrating thing is that when I open up an SQL Server Profiler trace on this with just about every single option selected, I get nothing.  I know that the code is hitting my SQL database because it returns results from the database but the profiler does not show anything happening.  This has made it pretty much impossible for me to troubleshoot.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the Event Logs? With custom code and such SSRS sometimes leaves a trace there, particularly if there's a problem loading certain assemblies.

Comment: Have you checked if it's using the same initial catalog on the report server?

Comment: Both good suggestions.  I'll try them out.

Comment: Nothing in the event logs on my machine or the report servers.  Not sure how or why it would be using a different initial catalog on the server since it is a connection string.

Comment: You are connecting to the database using integrated security. That works for you in BIDS but does the service account for SSRS have enough permission to run the stored procedure?

Comment: I just granted execute permission on the function to the service account but no luck.  Same issue.  Nothing shows up in SQL Profiler and nothing happens when I click on the link that exeuctes the custom code.